# Every time I boot my laptop I get asked to remove any media and restart, like you do after Ubuntu installation anyone know why this happpening?

Tags: installation, boot, media

I have Ubuntu fully installed on my laptop with no installation media in or attached. Everytime is boot my laptop it asks me to remove installation media and press enter to restart, like what happens after installation. I have never had this issue before with this laptop or any of my systems. Pleas help thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Have you got any CD/DVD in your drive?

Do you have any USB Flash drive plugged to your computer?

If it still does not boot, check your BIOS boot order and ensure that your Hard Disk is not on the top.

Comment: I have no USB, CD, DVD in my laptop as I said above I will check bios now, though the bios has not been changed for over a year and I have installed Ubuntu a few times since then.

Comment: Changing the bios did fix the issue just dont understand why I had to change the boot order, when I have never had to before. Thankyou though!

Comment: Glad it worked! Remember to mark the question as solved!